# How to push both sum of even and odd result from for loop into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Use for loop to iterate from 0 to 100 and print the sum of all evens and the sum of all odds. Print sum of evens and sum of odds as array

Output: [2550, 2500]

```js
let sumOfEven = 0;
let EvenOddArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i += 2) {
  sumOfEven += i;
}
console.log(sumOfEven);

let sumOfOdd = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i += 2) {
  sumOfOdd += i;
}
console.log(sumOfOdd);
console.log(EvenOddArr);
```

Comment: btw why 2 loops. you can check even or odd using % operator in 1 loop

Answer (score 3):

An easy-to-understand version:

```js
let sumOfEven = 0;
let sumOfOdd = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
     sumOfEven += i;
  } else {
     sumOfOdd += i;
  }
}

let evenOddArr = [sumOfEven, sumOfOdd];  
console.log(evenOddArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there - all you need is a couple of `push`es

```js
let sumOfEven = 0;
let EvenOddArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i += 2) {
  sumOfEven += i;
}
EvenOddArr.push(sumOfEven)

let sumOfOdd = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i += 2) {
  sumOfOdd += i;
}
EvenOddArr.push(sumOfOdd)

console.log(EvenOddArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the remainder of two as index for the array.

```js
const evenOddArr = [0, 0];

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) evenOddArr[i % 2] += i;

console.log(evenOddArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(Array(101).fill().reduce((a,_,i)=>(a[i%2]+=i,a),[0,0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative for when you have studied JS a bit more

```js
let sumArr = Array.from({ length: 101 })
  .reduce((acc,_,i) => (acc[i % 2] += i, acc), [0, 0]);

console.log(sumArr);
```